# mingw32-make.exe : *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

I have recently downloaded Net-SNMP module from their download page and was trying to build on Win OS. Below is the content of the Makefile:

```
!IF "$(LINKTYPE)" == "static"
libsnmp : libsnmp_
libsnmp_clean : libsnmp_clean_
!ELSE
libsnmp : libsnmp_dll_
libsnmp_clean : libsnmp_dll_clean_
!ENDIF
```

I changed all make command to  mingw32-make.exe as I am using MinGW32 and get the below error during build:

```
makefile:20: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

The contents pasted above is from line 20 onwards of Makefile.

How to resolve the issue.

Comment: This does not look like valid GNU Make syntax at all. It was probably written for some entirely different incompatible version of `make`. You'll want to peruse the accompanying documentation to find out the precise build toolchain requirements.

Comment: Let me guess: nmake.

Comment: Yeah, this is for nmake. GCC build should be done via `configure` (i.e. Cygwin or MSYS).